# MVC 5 Authentication working in IIS Express but not in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis

I have created an ASP .NET Web Application with MVC and Authentication as Individual User Accounts.
I have populated the app with some controllers, actions and views. Some of them are [AllowAnonymous] and other [Authorize].

It works perfectly in IIS express. I can create multiple accounts. And logging. And see the pages I have access to.

When I deployed the app to my local IIS, the authentication stopped working. I can create accounts. But I cant log in. When I try to log in it only redirects me toward the home page and I cant see the pages. When i try to put fake access it detects that they are incorrect.

I tried to fiddle around in the IIS settings but a don't know what to do.

Please, help me.

Comment: were you ever able to solve this problem? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, for the site search for Authentication feature and enable windows authentication and disable Anonymous.

Comment: I tried that. It gives me an infinite url like that :http://localhost:94/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturn

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep your application to run anonymous authentication instead of windows authentication. Otherwise, you login page will get into infinite loop.

Besides,are you trying to connect a localdb with individual user account template in IIS?
Have you tried to set applciation pool like this in applicationhost.config and remove "AttachDbFilename=....." from your web.config connection string? If I take the steps above, I can get both register and create work in my IIS.

```
 <add name="my app pool" autoStart="true">
                <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" setProfileEnvironment="true" />
            </add>
```